# Get bitmap of another application window

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-xp

Attempting to get an image of another applications window in Windows XP.

I can do this in Windows 7, because of the DWMRegisterThumbnail API, and this works flawlessly. However, in Windows XP there is no DWM api and therefore I am relying on PrintWindow.

This application opens new windows for each "menu" (every time you press a button on its UI), and therefore you have to re-enumerate all its windows to find the newest one (In fact, FindWindow returns the newest anyway). It does crash at some points however, possibly due to my application still having a handle to one of its old windows?

This is my current code:

```
if (garminHwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;
        garminHwnd = FindWindow("CDP_FIELD_WND", String.Empty);
        IntPtr hdc = GetWindowDC(garminHwnd);
        if (hdc != IntPtr.Zero)
        {

            Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            IntPtr dc = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
            bool success = PrintWindow(garminHwnd, dc, 0);
            memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc);
       }
```

"bmp" is a Bitmap and is just displayed in a PictureBox at the moment. This is run approx 1/sec.

Is there a more attractive/easier way to do what i'm doing?